# Display errors after dialog confirm on the same page. Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, dialog

So far I have a html form that allows the user to post some data. This is the steps I need the form processing to happen.

1, Once the user has submitted the data on page A it then brings up a Jquery dialog window on page A to allow the user to confirm what they are doing is correct or not.

2, After clicking on yes on the dialog window I need it to take it to page A again. The same page will then process the logic according to if the button pressed was yes or no.

3, The logic will then redirect to page B or just output validation errors.

Page A

The form that allows the user to submit the data

```
 <form style="display:block" id="edit-user" name="input" action="" method="post">                   
                    <?php
                        if(isset($users)) {
                            echo "<select name='users'>"; 
                            foreach($users as $user) {

                                echo "<option value='".$user."'>".$user."</option>";

                            }
                            echo "</select> 
                            <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='edit-user'>";
                        }


                    ?>
```

The dialog window on Page A that pops up after the form post from the same page.

```
  if($_POST['edit-user']) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            dialogClass: "no-close smaller-text",
            resizable: false,
            height:160,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );

                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
                }

            }
        });
    });
</script>

<?php }  ?>
```

Any solutions to this? If there is another way of doing this entirely then please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Page A

```
<form id="edit-user" name="input" action="" method="post">
...your input fields here...
<button type="button" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Page A Script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('#submitBtn').on('click',function(){
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            dialogClass: "no-close smaller-text",
            resizable: false,
            height:160,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
                $('#edit-user').submit();

            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It listen to clicks on the button Submit if clicked it launchs your dialog and if the dialog is clicked yes it submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form style="display:block" id="edit-user" name="input" action="" method="post">                   
  <?php
     if(isset($users)) 
     {
        echo "<select name='users' id='users'>"; 
        foreach($users as $user) 
        {
          echo "<option value='".$user."'>".$user."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select> 
        <input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='validate();'>";
     }


  ?>
<script>
function validate()
{
 var user = getElementById('#users').value;
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        dialogClass: "no-close smaller-text",
        resizable: false,
        height:160,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                /*Do the client side validation.
                For server side validation make use of ajax. In 
                server side validation, handle rest of the script according to response.
                */
                if(VALIDATION FAIL)
                {//output error
                 $(this).dialog( "close" );}else{
                window.location.href = 'Url to Page B'; //If validation is success
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }

        }
    });
}
</script>
```